# convert array to dict

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I want to convert a list to a dictionary:

```
products=[['1','product 1'],['2','product 2']]
arr=[]
vals={}
for product in products:
    vals['id']=product[0]
    vals['name']=product
    arr.append(vals)
print str(arr)
```

The result is

```
[{'id': '2', 'name': 'product 2'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'product 2'}]
```

But I want something thing like that:

```
[{'id': '1', 'name': 'product 1'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'product 2'}]
```

Comment: Can't this be a more useful result `{'1': 'product 1', '2': 'product 2'}` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is create a new dictionary for each iteration of the loop.

```
products=[['1','product 1'],['2','product 2']]
arr=[]
for product in products:
    vals = {}
    vals['id']=product[0]
    vals['name']=product[1]
    arr.append(vals)
print str(arr)
```

When you `append` an object like a dictionary to an array, Python *does not make a copy* before it appends. It will append that exact object to the array. So if you add `dict1` to an array, then change `dict1`, then the array's contents will also change. For that reason, you should be making a new dictionary each time, as above.

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity sake you could also make this into a one liner:

```
products=[['1','product 1'],['2','product 2']]
arr= [{"id":item[0], "name":item[1]} for item in products]
```

Which yields:

```
[{'id': '1', 'name': 'product 1'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'product 2'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
products=[['1','product 1'],['2','product 2']]
arr=[{'id':a[0], 'name': a[1]} for a in products]

print str(arr)
```

Would also work

Answer (score 0):

```
products=[['1','product 1'],['2','product 2']]
arr=[]
for product in products:
    vals = {}
    for i, n in enumerate(['id', 'name', ....]): # to make it more dynamic?
      vals[n]=product[i]
    arr.append(vals)
```

or just use [0], [1] like stated in previous post